# FragmentPagerAdapter getItem error with ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I've looked at quite a lot of code and can't figure this out. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

It has to be something simple.
I'm showing most of the code. The error is in the next section.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

public static final int TAB_COUNT = 3;
public static InputMethodManager inputManager;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    // To control keyboard pop-up
    inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

}
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

This is where my error is. 
case 1 of `getItem`, Type mismatch: Cannot convert from MainActivity.HistoryFragment to Fragment. it is telling me to either change method return type to `HistoryFragment` or change return type of `newInstance()` to Fragment. Where I can't do either. Other examples I've seen look almost identical to my code. I have tried with and without passing an argument.

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            Fragment tipCalc = new TipCalcFragment();
            return tipCalc;
        case 1:
            // Fragment history = new HistoryFragment();
            return HistoryFragment.newInstance(i); //ERROR HERE
        case 2:
            Fragment stats = new StatsFragment();
            return stats;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And my `HistoryFragment` that extends `ListFragment`. In the end it won't be pulling from the `String[]` values but from database resources. I just wanted to setup a structure first and see it/play with the layout.

```
    public static class HistoryFragment extends ListFragment {
    // public HistoryFragment() {
    // }

    String[] values = new String[] { ... };

    static HistoryFragment newInstance(int num) {
        HistoryFragment history = new HistoryFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);

        history.setArguments(args);

        return history;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                values));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out after getting some sleep. I was importing android.app.ListFragment instead of android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

Comment: set project framework to 2.3.3 (if you don't need conditional stuff of 3+) so you can avoid this kind of problems

Comment: I will. It says I have to wait until tomorrow. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: I had this exact same problem! I was about to ask and I saw this question!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have a stupid question: WHY exactly do you have to do this? Why do you have to use use a `v4` support package instead of just the stock standard package?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe I second your question WHY! I am stuck at this, and supremely miffed that I need to use the Support library, why can't the actual library do it's intended work?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe so, I just found out why. FragmentPagerAdapter is only a class of the Support library. As such, you need to ensure you're using "support" fragments as well, so wherever you construct a new fragment, you have to ensure that fragment is using the support library's imports.

Comment: Specifically, you have to import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment in HistoryFragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to typecast to fragment before returning. So try this

```
Fragment history = HistoryFragment.newInstance(i);
return  history;
```